# Find library dependency version of Haskell executable

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Let's say I have a executable file produced by ghc. Now I want to know
which version of a particular library it was built with (like which
version of base/< insert other library here > it was built with ?) ?

Is it possible to find it ?

A more specific question - I want to know which version of `Cabal`
library is used by my `stack` executable.

Comment: If you are inside the project folder, you can run `stack list-dependencies` to see which version of `Cabal` is being used. That's not quite what you want though.

Comment: @Alec Thanks, yeah that's not quite what I want. I want to find out the library version of the dependency just from the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ongy from #haskell irc for this answer.

I can use the GNU's `strings` utility to find the information. To find
which version of `Cabal` my stack executable is using, I can do this:

```
strings ~/.local/bin/stack | grep -i Cabal-
```

That will spit out a big string and I can find this piece of
information in it:

```
/tmp/stack-upgrade7565/stack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-6.14/7.10.3/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/stack-1.2.1-IEWywJcSJuzIIEqkeEd87k:/home/sibi/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.17/7.10.3/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/Cabal-1.22.8.0-Ku2CIqstfjg7Z2SNHUypWH:/home/sibi/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.14/7.10.3/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/Glob-0.7.11-0WpLeizIORG0eUMRaKlYmO:/home/sibi/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.14/7.10.3/lib/x86_64-li....
```

And I can see `Cabal-1.22.8.0` in it.

To find the `base` library version, you can do

`executable +RTS --info` which will spit out the ghc version from
which we can find the base. Example:

```
$ stack +RTS --info
 [("GHC RTS", "YES")
 ,("GHC version", "7.10.3")
 ,("RTS way", "rts_thr")
 ,("Build platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Build architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Build OS", "linux")
 ,("Build vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Host platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Host architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Host OS", "linux")
 ,("Host vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Target platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Target architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Target OS", "linux")
 ,("Target vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Word size", "64")
 ,("Compiler unregisterised", "NO")
 ,("Tables next to code", "YES")
 ]
```

Thanks to @MarcelineVQ for the above tip.